# In C#, how could I move my label right at a certain speed to a certain area?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, animation, label

I'm trying to make my label which in its original position is top left. What I want to happen is when the program starts, it'll gradually in about 1.5 seconds in a glide motion go to the center top of the application.

So how could I do that? I'm pretty sure there's a variable(s) that needs to be set. I am using Windows Forms.

Comment: What kind of application are you developing? Windows Forms? WPF?

Comment: I am using Windows Forms.

Answer (score 2):

You can do several things:

- Use `Label` control
- Use `Timer` and tick 1.5 seconds interval for glide motion
- On the `Tick` event of the timer change the location of `Label.Location` gradually to the center top of the application

OR

- Subscribe to `OnPaint` event
- Manually draw the label via `Graphics.DrawString()`
- Reposition the location of the text via `DrawString()` location
- Use the `Timer` to invalidate the painting every 1.5seconds, and `Invalidate()` the text position

SAMPLE

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.InitializeTimer();
    }

    private void InitializeTimer()
    {
        this.timer1.Interval = 1500; //1.5 seconds
        this.timer1.Enabled = true; //Start
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int step = 5; //Move 5 pixels every 1.5 seconds

        //Limit and stop till center-x of label reaches center-x of the form's
        if ((this.label1.Location.X + (this.label1.Width / 2)) < (this.ClientRectangle.Width / 2)) 
            //Move from left to right by incrementing x
            this.label1.Location = new Point(this.label1.Location.X + step, this.label1.Location.Y);
        else
            this.timer1.Enabled = false; //Stop
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that the Timer.Interval should be in the area of 20-30ms as the resolution won't be better anyway. So the `float deltaX`should be calculated accordingly!

Comment: So Joel what would I put it on the part that you said " On the Tick event of the timer change the location of Label.Location gradually to the center top of the application" ?                               And TaW how would I implement what you just said?

Comment: @Shawdotion, added a sample source, that you can start with.

Comment: I really appreciate the sample code. As I implement and edit this code, I don't recognize "this" or with the period "this." at the beginning of some of your lines. What's the difference between using and not using "this".

Comment: `this` is a special keyword. It just mean to say that we  are identifying that controls exist in `this` class. To make the source code work, create a new windows form. Drag a `label` control and a `timer`. Make sure to make an event for `Tick`. Then the code above should work. Using `this` is optional.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!